# Floating Action Button, version 23.2 not hiding

Tags: android, android-design-library, floating-action-button

I use new support library version 23.2

```
com.android.support:design:23.2.0
```

In this version my FloatingActionButton not hidding, when I call `FloatingActionButton.hide()` method.

In support library version 23.1 -- it work perfect. 
Can anyone explain me, what is the problem?

Also, when I use 23.2 version, Android Studio Preview screen show me some internal error [image]

**EDIT**

So, with breakpoints and debug I found class FloatingActionButtonIcs, which has method hide(), and this method should hide FAB view. But, I found, that hidding animation was cancelled. Why? I don't know :(

Here is the class, which I said. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/ics/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButtonIcs.java?autodive=0%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F And there is method hide(). In anonymous animation listener triggered method `onAnimationCancel()` 
Here screenshot [image]

**EDIT 2**
Yeah!
I found problem! But I don't understand why it is not working. I start another ObjectAnimator on Another view. Here is some code snippet.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);

        final FloatingActionButton mActionToogleMode = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et);

        final ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(editText, "maxLines", 250);

        mActionToogleMode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // WHEN THAT ANIMATION START -- FAB NOT HIDDING
                animator.start();

                mActionToogleMode.hide(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
                        super.onHidden(fab);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Can you add a code snippet for this?

Comment: I just use FAB in layout (with layout_anchor and layout_anchorGravity), and in my code I call method hide() for this FAB.

Comment: Kind of hard to diagnose this without any code. I made a quick test project with a FAB in a `CoordinatorLayout` anchored to the bottom right and made an `onClick` for it that called `hide` and it worked fine.

Comment: Also, what android version is this occurring on?

Comment: I had tested in Samsung S4 (Android 5.0.1) and LG G4 (Android 6)

Comment: Strange. I created test project too, and FAB was hide. But in this project -- no (
I will continue research

Answer (score 0):

Use clearAnimation() on FAB before start your animation.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very long time I tried to solve this problem. I found, that my FAB really not hiding only with support-design 23.2. I did not found WHY.
I just changed my dependencies for 23.1 version
AND! It is very important, for some libraries with `transitive=true`, I added exclude string

```
exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: '*'
```

I hope it is will be fixed for me in newer versions of support library.